# Replacing text values in an int column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns which are essentially contain integar values but they are str and contain text as well as numbers.

How can I replace words like "ask for price" and "Kms" in this dataframe?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4mME.jpg)

car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('['Ask For Price',.]|.\d*', '').astype(int)

getting this error

car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('['Ask For Price',.]|.\d*', '').astype(int)

Answer (score 0):

you can coerce the non numric to Null

```
import pandas as pd
df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(int)
```